# Image binding performance in pivot

Tags: performance, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I have made a calendar control based on the pivot control. Every pivot item represents one month. In this way I don't have the annoying arrows, which usually everybody use to switch between the months and I really love the native way you can browse the calendar. The calendar itself is pretty fancy and in each cell for every day, I have several images. The problem is that the performance is awful. 
Initially I have bound the images visibility property with a bool property(using a converter), but I have read that the visibility binding isn't good, cause it redraws the UI elements again. Then I have decided to bind the Opacity property of the images with the same bool property from my ViewModel. The performance got better, but it is still slow. So, basically, I have a calendar with cells and 3-4 images in each cell. I am setting each image's visibility/opacity using binding, but in both ways the performance is very bad.

So, basically in each calendar cell I have 5 x this image:

```
<Image Source="../Images/blabla.png" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Opacity="{Binding IsBlaBla, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacityConverter}}" />
```

Have you guys have an idea how I can improve the performance? I am out of ideas. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your performance issue is one of the UI being slow to interact with, you might consider using David Anson's LowProfileImageLoader to alleviate the bottleneck affecting this.

[Keep a low profile [LowProfileImageLoader helps the Windows Phone 7 UI thread stay responsive by loading images in the background] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx)

[There's no substitute for customer feedback! [Improving Windows Phone 7 application performance now a bit easier with LowProfileImageLoader and DeferredLoadListBox updates] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Also, there are a lot of things you can look at to tune performance. Details in the latter parts of my answer in this Question.

[Design advices for quick navigation between view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606785/design-advices-for-quick-navigation-between-view/4610803#4610803)

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the [`CacheMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to [`BitmapCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716473/bitmapcache-when-and-how-to-use/4718104#4718104) to another question, it contains details of the `BitmapCache` option.

```
<Image Source="../Images/blabla.png" 
       IsHitTestVisible="False"
       Opacity="{Binding IsBlaBla, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacityConverter}}"
       CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
```

I also remember reading somewhere that the jpeg decoder is a lot faster than the png decoder. So, unless you need transparency, you could convert your images to jpeg.